# gridView.DataSource as DataTable is setting a null in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource

I am setting my gridview.datasource into a datatable variable as below:

```
DataTable dt = gvPaymentHistory.DataSource as DataTable;
```

The gvPaymentHistory.DataSource has a record, however, the dt is null after that line has executed.  How can I pass the Datasource records to dt?

**EDIT**

DataSource is  List collection of a class object. It's not a DataSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is to store the data source of the grid in view source when u r binding the data to the grid and then retrieve it from the view source every time you need it.

```
Gridview.Datasource = yourdatasource;
ViewState["mydatasource"] = yourdatasource;
```

While retrieving

```
DataTable dt = ViewState["mydatasource"] as DataTable;
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This will work, however, the case is incorrect - try to post syntactically correct code:

ViewState["mydatasource"] = yourdatasource;

and

DataTable dt = ViewState["mydatasource"] as DataTable

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

if the bidning type is list than try out

```
List<CodeEntity> data= gvPaymentHistory.DataSource as List<CodeEntity>;
```

or

```
   List<CodeEntity> codes = (List<CodeEntity>)gvPaymentHistory.DataSource;
```

---

check this

```
if(gvPaymentHistory.DataSource is DataTable)
   DataTable dt = gvPaymentHistory.DataSource as DataTable;
if(gvPaymentHistory.DataSource is DataView )
    DataView dv = gvPaymentHistory.DataSource as DataView;
```

Comment: Is BindingSource used in winforms?

Comment: @DotNetRookie = its part of asp.net

Comment: @PranayRana what namespace is used to get BindingSource? I am getting an error ("missing a using directive or an assembly reference")

Comment: if(gvPaymentHistory.DataSource is DataTable) // returns false;

Comment: @DotNetRookie that means that its not datatable or dataview just check the datasource type  you binding...

Comment: @PranayRana It's a List<T> collection of a class object. It's not a DataSet

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but I don't think that will work. I need to pass values from gvPaymentHistory.DataSource into a datatable; I will let you know soon if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way: Use [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)gvPaymentHistory.DataSource;
DataTable dt =((YourDataSetType) (bs.DataSource)).Tables[0];
```